# How do I increase the 'View Orbit' amount?

Tags: interface, 3d-view

I would like to change the amount of degrees per orbit whenever I press the <kbd>Numpad 4</kbd> or <kbd>Numpad 6</kbd> keys from **15** to **22.5** degrees.

How would I do this?

Comment: You can modify the short cuts in the user preferences panel (input tab) : 3D View/3D View (global) then search for "view orbit". In each you have a "roll" parameter which can be set to the value you want

Comment: Unfortunately the roll amount does a lot more than that. I suspect the roll amount is a multiplier modifier for the amount turned.

Comment: It seems to be in radians

Comment: A complement : you can type "pi / 8" (for instance) in these text boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting of the short cuts can be found in the user preferences, *input* tab.

Their names are '*view orbit*'. The tricky thing is that the values needs to be in radians.

But you can use Python (transparently) to define the value you want in degrees. So to have 22.5 degrees, type "pi/8".

[image]

Now you can orbit with the wanted rotation :

[image]

Edit : you can also type "radians(22.5)". It seems all the math functions (math Python module, probably) are available.

Comment: That right there is freakin' PERFECT. Thank you!